# Metabox not show in categories custom post type cmb2

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, metabox, post-meta

it is possible to add a field in the categories (tags) in taxonomy?

[image: Image of Category taxonomy]

**this is my code in functions.php**

```
function post_types(){
    register_post_type('products',array(
            'labels'            => array(
            'name'              => 'Product',
            'singular_name'     => 'Product',
            'all_items'         => 'All product',
            'add_new_item'      => 'add new item a Products',
            'edit_item'         => 'Edit Product',
            'search_items'      => 'Search Products',
            'not_found'         => 'No found products.',
            'not_found_in_trash'=> 'nothing.',
             'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => false),
        ),
        'public'            => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-slides',
        'supports'          => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes','common'),
    ));
    }


add_action('init','post_types');

function create_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy('categoryx', array('products'), array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Categories'
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'items')
    ));
add_action('init', 'create_taxonomies');
```

**I tried using the example of cmb2**

```
function yourprefix_register_taxonomy_metabox() {
    $prefix = 'yourprefix_term_';
    /**
     * Metabox to add fields to categories and tags
     */
    $cmb_term = new_cmb2_box( array(
        'id'               => $prefix . 'edit',
        'title'            => esc_html__( 'Category Metabox', 'cmb2' ), // Doesn't output for term boxes
        'object_types'     => array( 'term' ), // Tells CMB2 to use term_meta vs post_meta
        'taxonomies'       => array( 'categoryx', 'post_Tag' ), // Tells CMB2 which taxonomies should have these fields
        // 'new_term_section' => true, // Will display in the "Add New Category" section
    ) );
    $cmb_term->add_field( array(
        'name'     => esc_html__( 'Extra Info', 'cmb2' ),
        'desc'     => esc_html__( 'field description (optional)', 'cmb2' ),
        'id'       => $prefix . 'extra_info',
        'type'     => 'title',
        'on_front' => false,
    ) );
    $cmb_term->add_field( array(
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Term Image', 'cmb2' ),
        'desc' => esc_html__( 'field description (optional)', 'cmb2' ),
        'id'   => $prefix . 'avatar',
        'type' => 'file',
    ) );
    $cmb_term->add_field( array(
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Arbitrary Term Field', 'cmb2' ),
        'desc' => esc_html__( 'field description (optional)', 'cmb2' ),
        'id'   => $prefix . 'term_text_field',
        'type' => 'text',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'yourprefix_register_taxonomy_metabox' );
```

Comment: the `object_types` should be `array( 'term' )` https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/blob/b1a7e8fb9f0634337b390a098f0a1f70f0f64085/example-functions.php#L601-L641

Comment: yes, sorry, does not work

Comment: Its working fine for me. you didn't close the function `create_taxonomies`. how did you installed the cmb2?